# NodeJS - Should we return instead of await to improve performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, async.js

When taking [this eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await) into consideration it looks like this kind of code should be avoided (even though the rule allows it when it is not "return await")

```
async function foo() {
    await bar(); // "cost of an extra microtask before resolving the outer Promise"
} // void return
```

And changed to

```
async function foo() {
    return bar(); //This may be confusing because there is no real return value
}
```

So the question is - is this "extra microtask" really that significant?

Obviously when looking on 1 function - the effects are negligible, but what if it happens a lot all over the codebase?

Comment: The rule is about `return await bar();` (_"Disallows unnecessary return await"_). `await bar();` should be correct. It's the second correct example but without `return;` at the end.

Comment: Short answer is no. Also premature performance optimisation is the root of all evil. You have to measure to make performance improvements. https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html

Comment: @jabaa Yea I know I brought the rule as reference

Comment: We're talking about one micro task. That's some microseconds.

Comment: I will agree with "premature optimization is the root of all evil" - don't do it, unless you know you have a performance problem (and then it's almost surely because of other reasons). Towards the other point, i was first a proponent of "no `return await`", but it appears that `return await` has important benefits when debugging, as you get much cleaner async stack traces, probably outweighing the little effect it has to keep it in memory.

Comment: The title is _"Should we return **instead** of await to improve performance"_ The actual question should be `return bar();` vs `return await bar();`. _"what if it happens a lot all over the codebase?"_ If it happens 1,000,000 times you have a runtime difference of a few seconds.

Comment: @jabaa - My question is specifically about returning when there is no return value just to improve performance

Comment: Why the `return` though, does it have any benefit? What about just `bar();`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte You can't await without `return`, can you?

Comment: Do `await bar();`, so that `foo` stays in the async call-stack until the Promise has resolved (then if it rejects you get a better stack trace)

Comment: @Jabaa i don't understand, of course you can `await` without `return`, but i don't get what you are aiming at.

Comment: @ASDFGerte You can't `await foo()`. It won't wait for `bar`: https://jsfiddle.net/runoqcv7/

Comment: Ahh, i understand what the intention is now, thanks. I misunderstood what you were talking about :)

Comment: In general, unless you intentionally do not want to wait for the Promise to resolve, you should do the opposite of that ESLint rule. That's why it's been removed from the recommended rule list. Always use `return await` when returning a Promise from an async function, and just `await bar();` if you want to return a Promise that resolves with `undefined`.